# SQL Server query multipart Identifier cound not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fill a table with data from two tables from  two different databases on the same server .

```
insert into emsoluciones.dbo.incoming (volumen, fechaini, fechafin, placa, nombreconductor, pk_consecventa)
   select 
       volumen, fechaini, fechafin, placa, nombreconductor, ventacliente.pk_consecventa
   from 
       estacion.dbo.venta, estacion.dbo.ventacliente
   where 
       venta.pk_consecventa = ventacliente.pk_consecventa 
       and ventacliente.pk_consecventa != emsoluciones.dbo.incoming.pk_consecventa
```

it works but if I want to do it again  to  update the info  it adds all the data on table  so I add : `ventacliente.pk_consecventa != incoming.pk_consecventa`

but it gives me the error

> multipart Identifier  incoming.pk_consecventa could not be bound

student here , thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @marc_s . . . Especially if the OP is a student.  What teacher would allow such things these days?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I'm myself amazed at how many folks still seem to learn it this way - more than 20 years after it's been discontinued

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude items using a field in the table you're inserting into, you need to JOIN to that table in your query.  Should be something like this:

```
insert into emsoluciones.dbo.incoming (volumen, fechaini, fechafin, placa, nombreconductor, pk_consecventa)
   select 
       volumen, fechaini, fechafin, placa, nombreconductor, ventacliente.pk_consecventa
   from estacion.dbo.venta
   JOIN estacion.dbo.ventacliente 
        ON  venta.pk_consecventa = ventacliente.pk_consecventa 
   LEFT JOIN emsoluciones.dbo.incoming.pk_consecventa
        ON ventacliente.pk_consecventa = emsoluciones.dbo.incoming.pk_consecventa
   WHERE emsoluciones.dbo.incoming.pk_consecventa IS NULL
```

You'll also have to add the table alias for all the fields since you're joining to a table that has all those fields too.